# How to use macro in C to select a type and specific functions depending on the type chosen?

Tags: types, macros, clang

I have a piece of C code where I define some data structures on a fundamental type. I would like to define this fundamental type through a macro to make it changeable, something a la:

```c
#define F_TYPE float                  // will use float as the fundamental type
// #define F_TYPE double                 // will use double instead
```

As a consequence, I need to do a bit of picking of the right functions depending on the type. For example, for `float` I should use `fabsf` from `<cmath>`, but for `double` I should use `fabs`. Something a la:

```c
#if (F_TYPE == float)
    #define F_TYPE_ABS(x) fabsf(x)
#elif (F_TYPE == double)
    #define F_TYPE_ABS(x) fabs(x)
#else
    #error "need to specify math functions to use with type F_TYPE"
#endif
```

But this does not seem to work: my compiler provides warnings of the kind:

```
In file included from tests_vec3.cpp:2:0:
../src/kiss_clang_3d.h:27:16: warning: "double" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
 #define F_TYPE double
                ^
../src/kiss_clang_3d.h:32:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘F_TYPE’
 #if (F_TYPE == float)
      ^~~~~~
../src/kiss_clang_3d.h:32:16: warning: "float" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
 #if (F_TYPE == float)
                ^~~~~
```

Any idea how I could make something like this work? I am most likely missing something about how I should use macros.

Comment: You can solve this problem with macros, but is there a reason why [`_Generic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) doesn't work?

Comment: Aaah, you are right, this may be the solution. I was just not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, `_Generic` would do the trick. However, for some other reason, I still wanted to stick with some flag and `#define` macros and logics. For the records, this is the kind of solution I ended up using; a bit verbose maybe (let me know if you know of something better :) ), but does the trick:

```c
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

// what fundamental type do we want to use?
// if the F_TYPE_SWITCH is set (by defining the macro earlier, either before #includ-ing, or
// by defining the compilation flag -DF_TYPE_SWITCH="'X'" where X is the type flag wanted),
// use it, otherwise, use the value set under.
#ifndef F_TYPE_SWITCH
  // double is 'D', float is 'F'
  #define F_TYPE_SWITCH 'D'
#endif

// this is C, no overloading, we need to adapt a bit to what sort of fundamental type we want to use
#if (F_TYPE_SWITCH == 'F')
    #define F_TYPE_2 (2.0f)

    #define F_TYPE_ABS(x) fabsf(x)

#elif (F_TYPE_SWITCH == 'D')
    #define F_TYPE_2 (2.0)

    #define F_TYPE_ABS(x) fabs(x)
#else
    #pragma message "The value of F_TYPE_SWITCH: " XSTR(F_TYPE_SWITCH)
    #error "invalid F_TYPE_SWITCH admissible switches are F (float) and D (double)"
#endif
```